# JetBrains Rider or Dotnet Core Cache issue with Blazor WASM

Tags: .net-core, jetbrains-ide, blazor-webassembly, rider

Blazor WASM, I have to clean my project every time I make a change to an Blazor class library.  IF I don't it's EXTREMELY unreliable if my browser will show the updated version (sometimes it works, sometimes not).  This is an absolute horrible development experience considering it takes 2 or 3 minutes to recompile everything every time.

Does anyone else have this issue? How could this slip through the cracks of the dotnet team and JetBrains.  Surely I'm not the only one with the issue.  Is there a way to fix this?

Yes, I'm using JetBrains Rider on a Mac.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Answered it myself, best way to solve the issue is to run the web client project defined in launch settings, and the server/webapi seperate.

Sometimes the build process doesn't copy the dlls and content from client libraries to the host project properly.